# User input in simple C++ counter program

Tags: c++, loops, user-input

I'm trying to make a simple counter program in C++ that will increment a variable with user input (specified by pressing a certain key). Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int variable;
    char userInput;
    variable = 0;
    cout << "To increment variable one, press a \n";
    do
    {
        variable = variable++;
        cout << "variable++ \n" ;
    } while (userInput = "a");
}
```

I have perused several related threads on this site and believe this should work. However, I get several errors, including that the operation on variable is not defined and that there has been an "invalid conversion" from "const char" to "char."

Answer (score 1):

Add cin in your loop:

```
    cin>>userInput;
```

and change

```
variable = variable++;
```

to

```
variable++; // or variable = variable + 1;
```

next you while condition should be like this:

```
 while (userInput=='a');
```

So your overall program will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
int variable;
char userInput;
variable = 0;
cout << "To increment variable one, press a \n";
do
{
    cin>>userInput;
    variable++;
    cout << "variable++ \n" ;
} while (userInput=='a');
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop you need a [std::cin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), like

```
cin >> userInput;
```

Moreover, the following line

```
variable = variable++;
```

will produce [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read more about [Sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) for better understading.

Try:

```
variable = variable + 1;
```

Finally in the while loop breaking condition, instead of assignment operation

```
while (userInput = "a");
```

Use comparison like:

```
while (userInput == "a");
```

Comment: Doesn't really solve the "Invalid Conversion" the OP is getting because of assignment in the while statement instead of comparison.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, ty, accidentally missed that.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use

```
std::cin >> userInput; // each time you go through the `do` loop.
```

Also, you just need to use

```
variable++; // on the line.
```

Also! Use `cout << variable << "\n";`

Lastly, use

```
} while(strncmp((const char*)userInput,(const char*)"a",1));
```

Comment: Doesn't really solve the "Invalid Conversion" the OP is getting because of assignment in the while statement instead of comparison.

Comment: `strcmp` takes pointers to null-terminated strings, not individual characters.

Comment: I tried it - it does not work. Also, why, in the first place, would you want to use a function designed for `char*` when all you have is simple `char`s?

Comment: I don't need to try it to know that it doesn't work.

Comment: Whats it say? And I wonder if you've used strncmp() in a while. I'm not using `strcmp` I'm using `strNcmp` big difference

Comment: `(const char)` and `(const char*)` is another big difference, and even with the "correct" cast the code is still wrong.

Comment: True, the pointer thing. How's the code wrong withthe correct cast?

Comment: Do not use C-style casts. Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. If those don't work, 90% of the time something is wrong in your code.

Comment: Answer me this, why does it need a pointer cast to be correct? It's one char.

Comment: Right, its made for bigger things than one char. Gotcha. Thanks, did it compile with the `n`?

Comment: You are the one who assured me it works, I'm not going to fix it for you.

Comment: Whatever. It works fine without your help. Except for the pointer cast.